# How can I order each product variant in my templates?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

In Craft Commerce is it possible to order each product variant in the template, I would like to order by price ascending, I've tried the below but nothing is returned?

```
{% for purchasable in product.variants.order('price asc') %}
```

Below works but displays in order they were added:

```
{% for purchasable in product.variants %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`product.variants` just returns an actual array of the variants, not an ElementCriteriaModel. So you can’t chain on additional params like `order`.

To get variants using custom parameters, you can do this:

```
{% set variants = craft.commerce.variants({
    product: product,
    order: 'price asc'
}) %}

{% for purchasable in variants %}
    // ...
{% endfor %}
```